# Change fonts and line thicknesses on a matplotlib figure that has already been created

Tags: python, matplotlib

Often, I create a figure that I'd like to use in a published article as well as on powerpoint slides.  What looks good in print doesn't always look good on a slide.  I'd like to create a matplotlib figure, save it, then update the font and line thicknesses and save again.  How can I push updated rcParams to a figure that's been made?

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
x = np.arange(100)/99.*4.*np.pi
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Nice title')
plt.savefig('default.pdf')
update_rcParams(font=20, thick=5)
plt.savefig('publish.pdf')
update_rcParams(font=30, thick=10)
plt.savefig('slide.pdf')
```

What would that `update_rcParams` look like?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to make sweeping changes like that, because rcParams is used to instantiate a bunch of objects (line objects, text objects, etc. which all come together to make the plot), and after they are created they don't care at all what rcParams is.  You can, however, modify the objects themselves ... for example, to change the font size for the axis labels you can get the actual text objects and modify them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xlbl = ax.set_xlabel('X axis label')

xlbl.set_fontsize(20)

plt.show()
```

Or, if you didn't save the individual object (i.e. you just called `ax.set_xlabel()` or `plt.xlabel()`), you can grab it from the Axes hierarchy:

```
ax = plt.gca() # gets the current Axes object
xlbl = ax.xaxis.get_label() # gets the Text object for the x axis label
```

For the sweeping changes you want, you'll need to write your own function that goes and modifies the items of interest.  Hopefully this will get you going in the right direction.